# Suppress reloading of ui-router based view on query parameter change

Tags: angularjs, anchor, angular-ui-router

**Updated question**

Question in title still stands - is it possible to catch `?parameters` and cancel view reload.

**Original question**:
I need to add anchor support for my application (anchors to topics).

Here's how far I am:

```js
angular.module('app.topics', [
    'ui.state',
    'ui.router',
    'restangular'
    'app.topics.controllers'
])
.config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('viewtopic', {
        url: '/topics/:slug?section',
        onEnter: function($stateParams) {
            // Works, as state has been reloaded.
            console.log('$stateParams', $stateParams);
        },
        resolve: {
            topic: function ($stateParams, Topic) {
                // Wrapper around Restangular. Returns promise.
                return new Topic().get($stateParams.slug);
            }
        },
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'TopicCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'topics/templates/details.tpl.html'
            },
            'sidebar': {
                controller: 'SidebarCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'topics/templates/sidebar.tpl.html'
            }
        }
    });
});

angular.module('app.topics.controllers', [])
    .controller('TopicCtrl', function ($scope, topic, $rootScope, $location,
                                         $anchorScroll, $stateParams) {
        $scope.topic = topic;
        $scope.slug = $stateParams.slug;
        $scope.section = $stateParams.section;
        // ..

        $scope.$watch('$stateParams.section', function (newValue, newValue) {
            // Does not work.
            console.log('stateParams.section changed', newValue, newValue);
        });
    });
```

My root issue is when I click on link with `#/topics/slug-name?section=section-1`, state is reloaded completely, which in turn re-requests data for Topic. How can one just "refresh" query parameters (and catch that event in controller) but don't reload state (to keep data loaded)?

**EDIT**

For my issue there is a rather simple solution which I've failed to notice -
per [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) on "Hashbang and HTML5 Modes" - last hash is accessible via `$location.hash()` and scrolling can be initiated by `$anchorScroll()`

So my current solution is:

In controller:

```
$scope.$watch('$location.hash', function () {
    _.defer($anchorScroll);
});
```

Defer is needed because content may not be parsed yet and there are no id's.

In template I just had to set target to `#/topics/slug-name#section-name`.

Comment: There are events emitted by uiRouter. For example there is a '$viewContentLoading' event https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#wiki-view-load-events  Have you tried catch it and stop before view rendering happened ?

Comment: It feels like you have found a solution with `$location.hash()`. What did you expect when you started the bounty?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried `reloadOnSearch` parameter within routes definition?

```
{
    route:'/',
    resolve: {
        templateUrl:'template.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }
},
```

Answer (score 20):

My two cents

First check @doodeec answer about setting up `reloadOnSearch` to false:

```
{
    route:'/',
    resolve: {
        templateUrl:'template.html',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }
},
```

Then on the controller you want to catch this:

```
/* Setup to detect when there is a change in the search */
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(next, current) {
   // Do something when routeupdate is called. 
});
```

I case you want to change the search:

```
$location.search({'slide_id': slide_id})
```

Also take care for a small Gotcha:

If your route params do not change (or change to the same value) since reload is disabled then you might need to force the location change:

```
$scope.$emit('$locationChangeSuccess');
```

From comments:

Without `ngRoute` there will be no $routeUpdate event. in this case you need to listen to `$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', ...)` instead

Comment: This is it. Note to ui-router users - `reloadOnSearch: false` has to be put directly in state and is supported in ui-router since 0.2.5. I'm marking doodeecs' answer as correct solution but bounty goes to you, for such great example.

Comment: angular-ui-router does not fire $routeUpdate

Comment: @AndreyKouznetsov   `$scope.$emit('$locationChangeSuccess');` does that!

Comment: @JimmyKane only if angular-route is present though it should not be included when ui-router is used.

Comment: @AndreyKouznetsov Correct yes.

Comment: $scope.$emit('$locationChangeSuccess') is the key! Very useful.

Comment: Just to add: Without `ngRoute` there will be no `$routeUpdate` event. in this case you need to listen to `$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', ...)` instead

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by using nested states. the code will look something like this

```
 $stateProvider.state('viewtopic', {abstract:true,
url:/topics,
resolve: {
            topic: function ($stateParams, Topic) {
                // Wrapper around Restangular. Returns promise.
                return new Topic().get($stateParams.slug);
            }
        },
views: {
templateUrl:<template>
}
});

$stateProvider.state('viewtopic.impl', {abstract:true,
        url: '/:slug?section',
        onEnter: function($stateParams) {
            // Works, as state has been reloaded.
            console.log('$stateParams', $stateParams);
        },

        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'TopicCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'topics/templates/details.tpl.html'
            },
            'sidebar': {
                controller: 'SidebarCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'topics/templates/sidebar.tpl.html'
            }
        }
```

for more read ->https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views