# Change page's location hash in angularjs app without page reloading

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to change page's location hash (e.g. from "#/" to "#/page1") so that angularjs won't reload the page. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in route definition, add this parameter
`reloadOnSearch: false`

[Supress reloading of ui-router based view on query parameter change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425378)