# How to set mandatory route parameters

Tags: angular-ui-router

I want to make a route with has a mandatory parameter. If not, it should fall into

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");`

Current route:

```
function router($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("settings", {
            url: "^/settings/{id:int}",
            views: {
                main: {
                    controller: "SettingsController",
                    templateUrl: "settings.html"
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Currently both the routes below are valid:

1. http://myapp/settings  *//Should be invalid route*
2. http://myapp/settings/123

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO, there shouldn't be a problem with accessing the `/settings` path, since it doesn't correspond to any state.

The actual issue should happen when accessing the `/settings/` path, because it will assign the empty string (`""`) to the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [state change start listener](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) to check if params were passed:

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      if(toState.name==="settings")
      {
          event.preventDefault(); //stop state change
          if (toParams.id===undefined)
           $state.go("home");
          else
           $state.go(toState, toParams);

      }
  });
```

Comment: I have several destinations which require mandatory parameter. It would become an extremely large if/else block with the example above. Is there some generic way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is valid for ui-router 1.0.0:

```
.config(($stateProvider, $transitionsProvider) => {

  //Define state
  $stateProvider.state('verifyEmail', {
    parent: 'portal',
    url: '/email/verify/:token/:optional',
    component: 'verifyEmail',
    params: {
      token: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      optional: {
        value: null,
        squash: true,
      },
    },
  });

  //Transition hooks
  $transitionsProvider.onBefore({
    to: 'verifyEmail',
  }, transition => {

    //Get params
    const params = transition.params();

    //Must have token param
    if (!params.token) {
      return transition.router.stateService.target('error', {
        type: 'page-not-found',
      });
    }
  });
 })
```

The above will make the `:token` parameter mandatory and the `:optional` parameter optional. If you try to browse to the page without the token parameter it will fail the transition and redirect to your error page. If you omit the `:optional` parameter however, it will use the default value (`null`).

Remember to use `squash: true` on the trailing optional parameters, because otherwise you'll also get a 404 if you omit the trailing `/` in the URL.

Note: the hook is required, because if you browse to `email/verify/` with a trailing slash, ui-router will think the token parameter is an empty string. So you need the additional handling in the transition hook to capture those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I had to make required parameters for a lot of routes.  So I needed a reusable and DRY way to do it.

I define a `constants` area in my app to access global code.  I use for other things as well.

I run this `notFoundHandler` at app config time.  This is setting up a router state for handling errors.  It is setting the otherwise route to this error route.  You could define a different route for when a required parameter is missing, but for us this was defined as being the same as a 404 experience.

Now at app run time I also define a `stateChangeErrorHandler` which will look for a rejected route resolve with the 'required-param' string.

```js
angular.module('app')
    .constant('constants', constants)
    .config(notFoundHandler)
    .run(stateChangeErrorHandler);

// use for a route resolve when a param is required
function requiredParam(paramName) {
    return ['$stateParams', '$q', function($stateParams, $q) {
        // note this is just a truthy check.  if you have a required param that could be 0 or false then additional logic would be necessary here
        if (!$stateParams[paramName]) {
            // $q.reject will trigger the $stateChangeError
            return $q.reject('required-param');
        }
    }];
}
    
var constants = {
    requiredParam: requiredParam,
    // define other constants or globals here that are used by your app
};

// define an error state, and redirect to it if no other route matches
notFoundHandler.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function notFoundHandler($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        //abstract state so that we can hold all our ingredient stuff here
        .state('404', {
            url: '/page-not-found',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: "/app/error/error.tpl.html",
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                $title: function () { return 'Page Not Found'; }
            }
        });

    // redirect to 404 if no route found
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page-not-found');
}

// if an error happens in changing state go to the 404 page
stateChangeErrorHandler.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state'];
function stateChangeErrorHandler($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        if (error && error === 'required-param') {
// need location: 'replace' here or back button won't work on error page
            $state.go('404', null, {
                location: 'replace'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now, elsewhere in the app, when I have a route defined, I can make it have a required parameter with this route resolve:

```js
angular.module('app')
    .config(routeConfig);

routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', 'constants'];

function routeConfig($stateProvider, constants) {
    $stateProvider.state('app.myobject.edit', {
     url: "/:id/edit",
     views: {
      '': {
          template: 'sometemplate.html',
          controller: 'SomeController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
      }
     },
     resolve: {
      $title: function() { return 'Edit MyObject'; },
// this makes the id param required
      requiredParam: constants.requiredParam('id')
     }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that there *shouldn't be* any problem with accessing the `/settings` path, since it doesn't correspond to any state, unless you've used *inherited* states (*see below*).

The *actual* issue should happen when accessing the `/settings/` path, because it will assign the *empty string* (`""`) to the `id` parameter.

## If you didn't use inherited states

Here's a [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/bbz3hzI99qciXT3BW0CO?p=preview) in plunker for the following problem:

> accessing the `/state_name/` path, when there's a state with url `/state_name/:id`

#### Solution explanation

It works through the [onBefore](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onbefore) hook (**UI router 1.x** or above) of the *Transition service*, which prevents transitioning to states with *missing required parameters*.

In order to declare which parameters are *required* for a state, I use the `data` hash like this:

```
.state('settings', {
  url: '/settings/:id',
  data: {
    requiredParams: ['id']
  }
});
```

Then in `app.run` I add the `onBefore` hook:

```
transitionService.onBefore({}, function(transition) {
  var toState = transition.to();
  var params = transition.params();
  var requiredParams = (toState.data||{}).requiredParams || [];
  var $state = transition.router.stateService;

  var missingParams = requiredParams.filter(function(paramName) {
    return !params[paramName];
  });

  if (missingParams.length) {
    /* returning a target state from a hook 
       issues a transition redirect to that state */
    return $state.target("home", {alert: "Missing params: " + missingParams});
  }
});
```

## If you used inherited states

You could implement the same logic via inherited states:

```js
function router($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings'
    })
    .state('settings.show", {
      url: '/:id'
    });
}
```

then you'd need to add the `abstract` property to the *parent declaration*, in order to make `/settings` path *inaccessible*.

#### Solution explanation

Here's what the [documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#abstract) says about the *abstract* states:

> An **abstract** state can never be directly activated. Use an abstract state to provide inherited properties (url, resolve, data, etc) to children states.

The solution:

```js
function router($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('settings.show", {
      url: '/:id'
    });
}
```

*Note*: that this only solves the issue with `/settings` path and you still need to use the *onBefore hook* solution in order to also limit the access to `/settings/`.

Answer (score -1):

it is not very well documented, but you can have required and optional parameters, and also parameters with default values.

Here is how you can set required params:

```
function router($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("settings", {
    url: "^/settings/{id:int}",
    params: {
      id: {}
    },
    views: {
      main: {
        controller: "SettingsController",
        templateUrl: "settings.html"
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I never used params with curly brackets, just with the semicolon, like this `url: "^/settings/:id"`, but from what I read, those are equivalent.

For other types of parameters, please see the other half of my answer here: [AngularJS UI Router - change url without reloading state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state/24835569#24835569)

Please note that when I added that answer, I had to build ui-router from source, but I read that functionality has been added to the official release by now.

Comment: So what makes the parameter mandatory? -
adding `^` to the `url` template
or defining a `params` dictionary with keys which values are object literals?

Comment: based on my testing - neither do. also {} doesn't seem to be allowed as a default value for a param

Comment: this is quite invalid answer. The _params_ property only lets you declare params that are _not in_ the url, or set default values for _missing_ params.
First it's wrong to set a default value for the `id` param, and second - it's even more wrong to default an `int` parameter to an `object` value