# Using window.location within an angular aplication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am trying to use window.location.pushState to change url without a refresh in an angularjs application. The reason for this is because my whole logic behind routing is on done on the server side so I don't want to use html5 mode. However, after using pushState the url is changed to the required one and then immediately back to the previous one. I suspect that this is because I am changing the URL outside angular so $location service thinks that it should change it back to what it was before (since it is different). Are there any ways around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state Check this out.

Comment: Could it actually be the $routeProvider, what is changing the URL back to what you defined in the otherwise method?