# How to update the URL in the address bar but without reload to that URL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

How to update the URL in the address bar but without reload to that URL?

I found 2 solutions :

**Solution 1**:
Read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059844/2642351
Using `window.history.replaceState`.
However, when I implement it in my angularjs project it reverts back the URL immediately ot the previous one.

**Solution 2**:
Read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102139/2642351
This works for ngRoute however, Im using uiRouter. Is there a similar solution in uiRouter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS UI Router - change url without reloading state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $location.path() to change the url without reloading it.You can read about it from the link given below.

[Information on $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)