# Controller not initialise when using $location.path or $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Controller is not initialising on the same page when using $state.go or $location.href

I am using sidemenu in my ionic to app pass category Id to product page using service but data is not updating corresponding to current category Id. When I click aaa I am successfully redirected to product page and it alerts 1. Again form side menu when i click 'bbb' I get no alert. Also if I chose bbb at first then 2 is alerted and vice versa

**Side menu Template**

```
<ion-item  nav-clear menu-close ng-click="allproductpage(1)">aaa</ion-item>
<ion-item  nav-clear menu-close ng-click="allproductpage(2)">bbb</ion-item>
```

**Side menu controller**

```
$scope.allproductpage= function(a){
angular.extend(inpsf.inps, {act_cat : a})  // inpsf is service
$location.path('/app/allproducts')
}
```

**Product page**

```
.controller('AllproductsCtrl', function($scope,inpsf)
{
alert(inpsf.inps.act_cat)   
})
```

**P.S** I am using `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` in my .config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS UI Router - change url without reloading state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter inside the state path declaration and listen for `$routeChangeSuccess` if using `$location` or `$stateChangeSuccess` if using `$state`, since you are already on the `'/app/allproducts'` when you click the second menu item and the controller is already "in page". Try something like:

```
.controller('AllproductsCtrl', function($scope,inpsf)
{
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        alert(inpsf.inps.act_cat)  
    })
})


//where you config your states..
$stateProvider.state('/app/allproducts/:cat', {
```

Side menu controller

```
$scope.allproductpage= function(a){
    angular.extend(inpsf.inps, {act_cat : a})  // inpsf is service
    $location.path('/app/allproducts').search({act_cat: a})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following way.

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function(){ $state.go('yourpath') })
```