# How to set state parameter without reloading the Pagein Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the state in Angular Js. I want to add some field like date in url without reloading the state. So I have seen related link [AngularJS UI Router - change url without reloading state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state)
But I am still stuck in this problem.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary" ng-click="dumy()">Apply</button>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.dumy=function(){
  $scope.startDate="2017-07-26T09:30:00Z";     
  $scope.endDate="2017-07-26T18:30:00Z";       
}
```

**MODEL.JS**

```
.state('app.shine', {
              url: '/showData',
              params:{
                View:null,
                Edit:null,
                Enable:null,
                Delete:null
              },            
               views: {
                  "content@app": {
                      templateUrl: 'view/view.html',
                      controller: 'controller'
                  }
              },

          })
```

I want to set **$scope.startDate** value in the URL as a state or query parameter. If I reload the page then These parameter should be there in **URL** , But these parameter should be set after click on the Apply button. I am new in the angular js. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are injecting $location into your controller, then you can use $location.search to update the url without a page refresh.

```
$location.search( { object with query parameter values })
```

For example, I use something like this in one of my apps:

```
 this.$location.search({ key: this.linesQuery.order, id: this.lineIndex })
```

Comment: @ Mike Feltman How could I get this key value again in Controller?

Comment: var search=$location.search() will return you an object like the one above. It basically parses everything following the ? in the URL into an object.

Comment: Could you tell me how to check key is present in $location.search or not?

Comment: var foo = $location.search(); if (foo.key) {...)