# AngularJs scroll with $anchorScroll

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I'm trying to use $anchorScroll to scroll to an id if you click a paragraph. For some reason it only works if you click the paragraph twice.

View:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<p ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="gotoAnchor(item .visibleName)">    {{item .visibleName}}</p>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in items" >
<div id="anchor{{item .visibleName}}">
    <h1>{{item.idPrimary}}</h1>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.gotoAnchor  = function(x) {
    var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
    if ($location.hash() != newHash) {
      $location.hash('anchor' + x);
    } else {
      $anchorScroll();
    }
  };
```

Comment: That's because you only `$anchorScroll` when the `newHash` matches the current one... Why bother with the `if`?

Comment: Yes but even if i don' use the if i have to click twice.      $scope.gotoAnchor  = function(x) {
        var newHash = 'anchor' + x;
          $location.hash('anchor' + x);
          $anchorScroll();


      };

Comment: Since you seem to be following the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) are you sure your anchors are right? Ids must be unique, do any of your items have duplicate `visibleName`s?

Comment: Perhaps this question solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637614/anchorscroll-only-works-after-second-click

Comment: Yes I am sure that there are not any duplicates.